# Catch the click and store it till target script is loaded on page JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `onclick` function

```
<a onclick="func()"></a>
```

on the main page, user can click on this link before all script files are loaded on that page, so they will get "empty" click it they press the button too early.

**Note: I'm not looking for how to load the script faster/in sync with the main page.**

My question is how to "catch" this click and "store" it as long as it takes until target script is loaded and then proceed with the `click`.

My thinking that .promise() may do the trick but I never work with it before, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This isn't how JS is intended to work. A much better idea would be to only show content once the JS has been loaded. *That being said* it should not be taking more than 0.5s to load all the JS in to the page. If it is, then profile the page request to diagnose what is taking so long, and remove/update it.

Comment: The script load delayed for a reason (for 3000ms), it's not enough for a most user to start clicking, but some of them might. I want to create some insurance for this case @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your page, define an array where you will store all the clicks using the `push()` method. Then process them all when your js file is loaded.

```
<!-- HTML PAGE -->
<script>var clicks = [];</script>

<a href="#" onclick="clicks.push([func, this])">AAA</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clicks.push([func, this])">BBB</a>
<a href="#" onclick="clicks.push([func, this])">CCC</a>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT FILE  -->
<script>
    // The function executed by clicking on a link
    function func(node) {
        console.log(node.innerHTML);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        // When the page is loaded, rewrite the push() method
        // So, when you click on a link, it should execute the function instantly
        clicks.push = function (click) {
            var fn = click[0],
                node = click[1];
            fn.call(this, node);
        };

        // Execute all saved clicks
        for (var c = 0; c < clicks.length; c++) {
            clicks.push(clicks[c]);
        }
    };
</script>
```